# Oracle:ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT CName AS Cuisine, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM REST_CUISINE 
GROUP BY CName 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not have `limit` clause.
use:

```
SELECT
    cname    AS cuisine,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    rest_cuisine
GROUP BY
    cname
ORDER BY
    total DESC
FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: by the way, do u know how to add $ sign in oracle? select RESTAURANT_ODETAILS.Ono,sum(MENU.price * RESTAURANT_ODETAILS.Qty) as Total
from RESTAURANT_ODETAILS 
JOIN MENU 
on ( RESTAURANT_ODETAILS.RestId = MENU.RestId and RESTAURANT_ODETAILS.FoodName = MENU.FoodName ) 
group by RESTAURANT_ODETAILS.Ono